# Factoring out $x$ from equations containing $\cosh(xy)$

Tags: real-analysis, hyperbolic-functions, upper-lower-bounds

I have the following inequality:

$x < \dfrac{-z(x-1)(1+\cosh(xy))}{(1-z)(1+\cosh(y-xy))}$ 
where we know $x \in [0,1], y > 0, z \in (0,1)$ and $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $x \not<0 \implies (x-1) \neq 0 \implies (x-1) < 0$, this can also be written as:

$\dfrac{x}{x-1} > \dfrac{-z(1+\cosh(xy))}{(1-z)(1+\cosh(y-xy))} \iff \dfrac{x}{1-x} < \dfrac{z(1+\cosh(xy))}{(1-z)(1+\cosh(y-xy))}$ 
although I'm not sure this helps.

I need to rewrite this in terms of just $x$. So something like $x < f(y,z)$ is what I am looking for.

I am completely stuck on how to deal with $\cosh(xy)$ and $\cosh(y-xy)$. I don't even need a perfect bound for $x$, if I can get any improvement on the given bound of 1, that would be significant progress.

Is there any straightforward way to deal with products inside hyperbolic trig functions?

Comment: There is a major mistake. When you change signs in an inequality the $>$ becomes $<$ and vice versa. In other words should be $$\frac{x}{1-x} <\frac{z (\cosh (x y)+1)}{(1-z) (\cosh (y-x y)+1)}$$

Comment: Oh oops! I've fixed it, the whole point of changing the signs was to get the inequality in the right direction haha, messed up when I typed it out. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway I am quite hopeless to solve your inequality in a form $x< f(y,z)$

Comment: Thanks for trying, anyway!